# How to generate event handler automatically in WPF, C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently learning to code WPF application after having used forms for a while.
I have a simple question, but can't seem to find an anwser anywhere.

Is it possible to automatically generate the 'private void *eventName*(...' code when creating an event ?

For example, if I create a WPF Form with a simple button and code :

> Button x:Name = "mButton" Content = "Hello" Click = "mClick" /

Is there a trick to have the private void event handler create itself ? Cause right now, I either write it manually or double click in the event handler properties tab. In widowsForm, I could just double click and it would create itself. 
This isn't a big issue for 1 or 2 but if I want to create a dozen buttons, it can become tedious.

I apologize if the question can seem obvious

Comment: Don't. Your Code-Behind should be as empty as can be. Use a ViewModel and bind Commands.

Comment: When you write the event in XAML one of the options in the popup is "generate new event handler" which does exactly this.

Comment: @Alejandro Yes ! This works ! Is there a way to keep the name I want to input ? It generates a new name by itself

Comment: @Fildor I see what you mean, but I'm trying to create a context menu

Comment: @Astrashar I see. Nevertheless, I really, really recommend switching to MVVM. It will make you dizzy at first but soon enough, you'll love it. (Been there, done that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Of-course, the more automated and lazier the better.*
 So a few tips:

You can generate a new event handler with an automated name like this:

- Assign the `x:Name` **before** creating or assigning the event handler
- Pick the default `<New Event Handler>` from the list of options IDE gives you for your event handler. it will generate something like:

  `MouseDoubleClick="mButton_MouseDoubleClick"`
  or `Click="mButton_Click"`

If the name is already taken, it will be prefixed with `_1`

If the `x:Name` is not assigned, it will be prefixed with `Button_` instead of `x:Name`

---

You can generate any already-written event handler like this:

- Right click on handler's name in XAML code (`"mClick"`) and choose <kbd>Go To Definition</kbd> (The default shortkey is <kbd>F12</kbd>)

<kbd>F12</kbd> does the same thing as **double-clicking** on an event handler value in properties window in **WinForms**. In case of default event (like `Button`'s `Click`, it does the same as **double-clicking** directly on the control)

---

If you don't want the control to contain any code for event handler like:

```
 <Button /> // handles the click event magically
```

Then you can add this to the container of all the buttons:

```
<Container.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="mClick"/>
    </Style>
</Container.Resources>
```

*(obviously, I supposed the name of the container is `Container`. In your case it might be `Window` or `Menu` etc.)*

Now every button inside this container has its `Click` handled by the same handler, in which you can redirect your logic to the right method:

```
    Dictionary<string, Action> dic;
    private void mClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dic[(sender as Button).Name]();
    }
```

---

These all still so tedious compared to MVVM pattern:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myButtons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding ButtonAction}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: The F12 button does it for me. Thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this rather than use a databinding/command pattern, you can use the XAML designer in Visual Studio. If you start typing `Click="` you should be prompted with a list of possible event handlers or a new one - selecting one and pressing tab will create the event handler in the code behind for you (you might want to rename it, or make sure you name the button in XAML first).